# Image shattering effect in android

Tags: android, animation

Hay Guys i trying to develop an android game,in which i require an image shattering effect.When i searched for the logic i got one which is implemented in Iphone using Opengl and Cocos2d(i think)
What they are doing is splitting the entire image(texture) into small triangles and moving them in random direction with random speed.But i can not implement the code directly into the android project and, i do not know from where to start.Can anyone help me to split my texture into different small triangles..Thnks in advance..If demo code is required http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/19523 
Guys please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cocos2d-x instead for android

Comment: thanks for the reply.I know it been a long but i tried with the cocos2dx in android but the image shattering effect in not working.Could you please help me if i provided some coding details